# Force due to a concentric hemisphere on a sphere of smaller radius

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields

Recently while revisiting electrostatics I found a question

[image: relevant question]

now I know that a sphere imitates the electric field behavior of a charge, so to calculate the force on the hemisphere due to charge I would simply use the formula of electric field at the centre of a hemisphere multiplied by charge $$\sigma q /4\epsilon_{0}$$ but the problem is that this doesn't match the actual answer which is $$\sigma q/4\epsilon_{0}(1-1/{\sqrt 2})$$

I have 2 questions here:-

1. What is the problem in reducing the behavior of sphere to a point charge?
2. How to get the correct force?

As for 1) I think the reason why it doesn't work is because the field inside the sphere is different than wat we get in the case of a point charge, but then why should it matter? The field at each point of hemisphere is same in both the cases so we should get the same answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider the sphere as +q at centre, we reduce  behavior of sphere to a point charge because the electric field of it outside sphere is like point charge?

Comment: Hint: Think about components. How much vertical force is there on the hemisphere? Why? How much horizontal force?

Comment: I get the same as you.

Comment: @mmesser314 $F_v$ is $0$ due to spherical symmetry. $F_h$ only exists. More people confirm with the same answer as I first got. Did you get the 2nd answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if anyone is at all interested in this, but I think the established answer to this electrostatics problem, which seems to have circulated around a few websites online, is wrong. If you consult the answer key for this problem (which I believe is Q. 130 from *Problems in Physics for IIT JEE by Shashi Bhushan Tiwari, Vol. 2*), the first line states to set up the integration using the electric field from a charged ring on its axis,
$$E = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Qx}{(R^2+x^2)^{3/2}}$$
All good so far. Next, they set up the conversion to spherical coordinates:
$$r_0 = R \cos{\theta}$$
$$x = R \sin{\theta}$$
Here's where they go wrong—the solution key confuses the two radii in this problem. Where in the equation for the electric field of a ring, $R$ refers to the radius of the ring, in the second pair of equations $R$ refers to the constant radius of the hemisphere, while $r_0$ refers to what was previously $R$.

We see this in the next step of the solution:

$$dE_{ring} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{(Q\cos{\theta}d\theta)(R \sin{\theta})}{[R^2 + R^2\sin^2{\theta}]^{3/2}}$$

This line is wrong. It should read:

$$dE_{ring} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{(Q\cos{\theta}d\theta)(R \sin{\theta})}{[R^2\cos^2{\theta} + R^2\sin^2{\theta}]^{3/2}}$$

The difference between these two expressions accounts for the discrepancy between the answer key and the real answer.

Comment: I never found the book (my phy teacher didn't want to give away his source material lol) this is kind of useless for me now, but I appreciate the closure (prolly will help someone who was trying to find the answer to it) ^^

Comment: @napstablook Yeah I imagine it's not relevant for you now but I came across this while looking at the same problem and realized the error. Hopefully will save someone else some trouble.